# Не коректно выводится дата

Tags: javascript, angular

Мне нужно в ангуляр выводить дату которую я  записал в БД как параметр. Я вывожу  но в таком виде:

```
2018-01-02T00:00:00
```

а мне нужно в таком

```
2018-01-02
```

Как оставить только  дату а время убрать?

Comment: для *форматирования* даты в коде разметки следует воспользоваться *фильтром* [date](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Vova Makrovych, ты читал [документацию](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)? :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
var now = new Date();
var formated_date = now.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Либо через `moment.format()` (требуется наличие moment.js).

```
moment(testDate).format('YYYY_MM_DD');
```

Comment: я  так  сделал и получил ошибку что так  нельзя - {{show.date.format(""dd//mm//yy")}}

Comment: пробывал и так - {{show.date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать moment.js.

Comment: @VovaMakarovych предложенные способы подразумевают что у модели появляется свойство в котором отражается значение даты в виде строки, а Вы насколько я вижу хотите это написать в коде разметки, для этого есть фильтр [`date`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{show.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Вот так попробуй, не забудь | этот знак.